# FormatString in GridView ASP.NET to show Currency without the '$' symbol

Tags: asp.net, formatting

I'm using a GridView control in ASP.NET.

One of the columns has a currency value which requires that the '$' sign be not shown and the negative numbers be shown in parenthesis.

So my current FormatString for this column is

```
FormatString="{0:0,,0.00;(0,,0.00);0}"
```

Everything works fine, except the number 4.96 shows as 04.96. I can't figure how to fix this,
any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
FormatString="{0:#,,0.00;(#,,0.00);0}"
```

Comment: But this doesn't give me parenthesis around the negative numbers.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the parenthesis. Please try that.

Comment: I did, negative numbers show as

    -9,000 instead of (9,000)

Comment: Sorry, will delete. I'm away from a PC now. Will leave the up vote for the question though.

Comment: Back at a PC now, I think this is what you need.

Comment: This doesn't put in the commas at the thousands and millions place then.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31948/discussion-between-vivek-todi-and-hutchonoid)